# Spring jpa fetch eager not working on findById

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I m using spring and hibernate for my java object.

I have an entity like this :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Function implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   /** Code value. */
   private String code;
}
```

And another entity that reference the first one like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }),  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "code" }) })
public class RoleDef extends CodeLabelEntity{

...some other primitive type...

    /** List of functions */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_function",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "function_code", referencedColumnName = "code"))
    private Set<Function> functions;
}
```

I m using repository like this :

```
public interface RoleDefRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleDef, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<RoleDef> {
}
```

when i m doing in my roleDefService :

```
roleDefRepository.findAll();
```

I can iterate over RoleDef and functions beacause EAGER do the job
But when i'm trying to do:

```
RoleDef roleDef = roleDefRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
```

My functions Set inside the roledef is empty. findById is not overided, it's the default method like findAll.

If you see something that i ommit to delcare...

I m using last version of spring/hibernate

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any exception when you call `roleDefRepository.findById(id)`? or getting a null?

Comment: No in debug mode i can see my roledef correctly initialize but when i try to access to roledef.getfunctions i got empty Set

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by doing this in my repository :

```
 @Query("select r from RoleDef r join fetch r.functions where r.id = ?1")
 Optional<RoleDef> findByIdWithFunctionTree(Long id);
```

But if someone can find the real problem because i think EAGER on the relation or accessing by a get when transaction still open will do the same as the fetch...

Comment: I think i encounter same issue as yours.  But i did not use query method, i implement the logic myself using this.entitymanager.find(...) ...but the set of child entities still size 0.  But once i use JPQL, the set of child entities are popualted. Until now its still a mystery. And Yes, my entity is annotated with EAGER, not lazy.